# Unit Test fails with mock. Seems to be calling the function when it should be mocked and not being called at all. Can anyone help explain why?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs, mocking

I do not understand why this mocked function seems to be called despite it being mocked. Do I have it set up wrong? How should this unit test be set up in order to see if a 303 is returned within in the location header?

It looks like the function processing because it fails while reading 'domainName'. If it were not being called, it should never have gotten to that point. Am I wrong? I'm new this and very confused.

```
import nock from 'nock'
import { handler } from '../redirect'
import STATUSES from '../constants/purlStatuses.js'
import { UNAVAILABLE as _UNAVAILABLE, TECHNICAL_ISSUES as _TECHNICAL_ISSUES } from '../redirect/constants/redirectUrls.js'
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'

let expectedHeaders = {}
const cms = process.env.CMS
console.log("For testing, CMS=", cms)


// //************** GRAPHQL *****************/
if (cms == 'graphql'){
  describe('Redirect', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      getItem = jest.fn()
      expectedHeaders = { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*' }
    })

    afterEach(() => {
      expectedHeaders = {}
      nock.cleanAll()
    })

    it('returns 303 with Location header', (done) => {
      const dest = 'http://foo.bar.baz/'
      const key = 'test'
      const title = 'Title of link'
      const graphqlResponse = {
        data: [
          { 
            attributes: {
              key: key,
              title: title,
              destination: dest,
            }
          }
        ]
      }
      getItem.mockReturnValue(graphqlResponse)
      const scope = nock(process.env.STRAPI_ENDPOINT)
        .post(() => true)
        .reply(200, graphqlResponse)
      const input = { pathParameters: { key: key } }
      const context = {}
      expectedHeaders['Location'] = dest
      const mockLambdaCallback = (err, data) => {
        expect(data).toEqual({
          statusCode : 303,
          headers : expectedHeaders,
          body : null,
        })
        done()
      }
    handler(input, context, mockLambdaCallback)
  })
})
}
```

This is the error message presented when the test is run:

```
  ● Redirect › returns 303 with Location header

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'domainName')

      213 |         purlKey,
      214 |         context.awsRequestId || '65683d90-7eeb-46e7-892b-b38b32c779cf',
    > 215 |         input.requestContext.domainName,
          |                              ^
      216 |         input.requestContext.path,
      217 |         Object.keys(queryParams).map(key => `${key}=${queryParams[key]}`).join('&'),
      218 |       )

      at domainName (redirect/index.js:215:30)
```

Comment: What do you think is mocked here? `getItem` has no connection at all to the code you're supposed to be testing.